# How do I make :make run on a buffer write if I'm inside my project directory?

Tags: autocmd

There's [posts on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732657/vim-save-then-make-automatically#3732706) that explain how to do it in general or on files of a particular type but I would like to restrict it to when I'm inside my project directory.

I can run a script to determine whether I am. 
How I can I wire it up with vim?

In other words, how do I do something like?:

```
if  !myscript >/dev/null 2>&1 "doesn't work
    autocmd BufWritePost <buffer> make
endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another (untested) approach :

`:autocmd BufWritePost <buffer> make` and

`:let &makeprg="if ! myscript >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then make ; fi"`

I use `let &makeprg="..."` instead of `set makeprg ...` to avoid the ugly `\`-es.

Comment: It's not very pretty but this general approach is workable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then this might help:

`:autocmd BufWritePost <buffer> if !system ("myscript >/dev/null 2>&1") | make | endif`

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't appear to do it. If I replace `myscript` with `true` or `/bin/true` it runs, but it also runs with `false `o `/bin/false`, which shouldn't happen.

Comment: `system()` returns command's output, not its exit code. This could work: `:autocmd BufWritePost <buffer> call system('myscript >/dev/null 2>&1') | if v:shell_error | make | endif`